# Workbench crashes on schema comparison for a particular database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to compare schema for two environments by using the Workbench database compare functionality, For a particular database, on the final step, it just closes WorkBench with no messagebox or warning. For the rest of the database, it works fine.

I have tried to take a backup of the same database (no data) and restore it on some other server,then also got the same workbench crash issue.

Any leads should be appreciated.